# How to write java code for reading large CSV file using multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have about 10000 lines csv file and have to create 5 threads and each thread does its operation.
how can I divide 10000 lines into 5 thread? and then have to join all the 5 threads.
the csv file is about employee details so i have to get the values on the basis of the department,

Comment: Does each thread need to do something different? Are you trying to read 2000 lines per thread? When you say you need values based on department, does that mean that you are trying to group the information into arrays or some similar structure?

Comment: I would only use two threads - one to load up large buffers and push them onto a producer consumer queue, one to pop them and parse the data, byte-by-byte.  If you try to use multiple parse threads, it's gonna get messy at the start/end of the buffers where the data gets sliced up:(

Comment: I mean, just two threads isolates the parser from disk latency - do you need more gain than just that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.